# Display Firestore Doc by Id on click, from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

So, I've been using the Google's Friendlyeats example as guide. I changed it a bit in order to use Butterknife but had issues when trying to open a single doc (fragment) and show its content in the following activity.

I'm using a recyclerview to show the summarize data and then I want to show the full individual data on an activity. It's really not that much info, just four textviews.

Because of this, I decided to stick to the original example as much as I could to see what was up. Still same error. I can open the following activity but no data is being displayed.

I'm already three months behind lmao. please help!

here's the code:

**MessageAdapter.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            headerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_item_header);
            senderView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_item_sender);
            dateView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_item_date);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_item_image);
            actualMessageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.actual_message);
        }

        public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                         final OnMessageSelectedListener listener) {
            Messages messages = snapshot.toObject(Messages.class);


            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_app_off);

            headerView.setText(messages.getHeader());
            senderView.setText(messages.getSender());
            actualMessageView.setText(messages.getMessage());
            dateView.setText(messages.getDate());

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onMessageSelectedListener(snapshot);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
   @Override
   public void onMessageSelectedListener(DocumentSnapshot message) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MessageDetailActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, message.getId());
       startActivity(intent);

   }

   private void initFirestore() {
       mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

       mQuery = mFirestore.collection("messages")
               .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
               .limit(LIMIT);
   }

   private void initRecyclerView() {
       if (mQuery == null) {
           Log.w(TAG, "No query, not initializing RecyclerView");
       }

       mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(mQuery, this) {

           @Override
           protected void onDataChanged() {
               if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                   mMessagesRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               } else {
                   mMessagesRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
           }

           @Override
           protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
               Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                       "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       };

       mMessagesRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
       mMessagesRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
```

**DetailMessageActivity.java**

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_detail);




       String messageId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID);
       if (messageId == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass extra " + KEY_MESSAGE_ID);
       }

       mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

       mMessageRef = mFirestore.collection("messages").document(messageId);



   }

   @Override
   public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
       if (e != null) {
           Log.w(TAG, "message:onEvent", e);
           return;
       }

       onMessageLoaded(snapshot.toObject(Messages.class));
   }

   private void onMessageLoaded(Messages message) {
       mDetailedHeader.setText(message.getHeader());
       mDetailedHeader.setText(message.getSender());
       mDetailedMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
       mDetailedDate.setText(message.getDate());
   }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Yes, I now see my mistake. corrected and thanks!